# Git status is returning long list of files deleted

Tags: git

In Git pull I was getting merge conflict. So I deleted all the folders and files inside it which was giving conflict in my local workspace. After which I did :

```
git pull
```

Now no conflict came and my local branch became sync to remote branch.

Now when I am doing

```
git status
```

Its returning hundreds of deleted files which I removed. I assumed that most of the deleted files would be replaced by the existing files in remote but I was wrong.

How can I remove the deleted files in the git status. Its because I cannot read properly the actual files which I am going to modify or delete because of this list of files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reset local repository branch to be just like remote repository HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628088/reset-local-repository-branch-to-be-just-like-remote-repository-head)

Comment: When you delete a file GIT thinks you will want to send this delete to the repo. If you want to reset a local copy, deleting the files is the wrong thing to do

Answer (score 0):

Instead of deleting the files and folders that were causing conflicts, I suggest you create a new folder and run `git clone url`. This should be the same and up to date that's if you `push` the last update you made locally.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution : 
I used the below :

```
git pull

git reset --hard HEAD
```

all the deleted files got removed from changed files section in git status.

So the git status showed only untracked files which I removed using

```
rm <filename>
rm -r <directory name>
```

Then I was good to have a clean working directory .

Only things which are remaining are some autogenerated files from the IDE which I am using . I believe I have to use .gitignore files to ignore them.