# How can I remove all local commits and go to the last commit on the branch master (on remote repository)?

Tags: git, github

I have made some changes in the repository and registered a commit (on local). And then I executed this:

```
$ git pull origin master
```

And my local commit merged with the pulled one. Now I regret. I want to get the last version which is on the remote branch master and get ride of the local commit (which is merged).

I can change the working directory by this command:

```
// the last commit on the remove branch master
$ git checkout 84acc42 .
```

But if I make some changes on it and push it, I guess that previous changes still are exists and will be pushed as a commit too. Because that commit is exists.

Noted that `$ git reset --hard` doesn't remove anything. I executed that and still see the changes I don't want.

Any idea how can I get the last version which is on the remote repository (branch master) and remove everything else? I can do that by removing the local working directory and cloning it again from the repository. But I want to know if there is another way.

Comment: do you want to throw away all the changes and make it exactly like remote branch?

Comment: @MarufTuhin Yes.

Comment: For future reference, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628088/reset-local-repository-branch-to-be-just-like-remote-repository-head/12892133

Comment: I think the question that @MarufTuhin's comment is pointing to should be instead marked as the question that this question is duplicate of.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fetch the origin/master.

```
git fetch --all
```

Stage all the changes. So that, No untracked files will be left behind.

```
git add .
```

Then, run `reset` command,

```
git reset origin/master --hard
```

This will throw away all the changes made in the branch, will be exact copy of origin/master.

Comment: Why stage changes first?

Comment: Thank you, upvote. but I did it like this: `git fetch --all` and then `git reset --hard origin/master`

Comment: @Chris Git reset doesn't delete any unstaged new `files`. So, I stage them first before running git reset.

Comment: So it seems you're saying to run `git add .` to avoid having any untracked files (unless the match a `.gitignore` rule), because untracked files wouldn't be deleted; right?  As a more intuitive alternative, you could run `git clean`.  (Initially I specified running it after the reset, but I guess either way would work...)

Comment: @MarufTuhin, [`git reset --hard`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset#git-reset---hard) resets the index and the working tree. Do you mean un_tracked_ files?

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger, Yes. That's the reason. And, `git clean` makes better sense. :) .

Comment: @Chris, Yes Chris. un_tracked_ files it is. I forgot the exact word for it. My bad.

Comment: @MartinAJ, I missed that part . Now updated the answer.