# Clone a remote project in a new branch of fork.

Tags: git

I forked a remote repository A that I do not own and began to do changes on it. Let's call this fork B.

Then someone asked me to add some functionality to project A. However, I don't want to fork A again since the two forks would have the same name.

Is there a way to clone A in new branch of B?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628088/reset-local-repository-branch-to-be-just-like-remote-repository-head

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add A as a new remote (e.g. "upstream"):

```
git remote add upstream git@github.com:originalauthor/repo.git
```

Then you can check out that remote branch and turn it into a branch:

```
git checkout upstream/master
git checkout -b upstream-master
```

And then make your new changes on a branch diverged from that.

---

Ideally, you'll want to periodically rebase your changes on that branch, after pulling it:

```
git checkout upstream-master
git pull upstream --rebase
```

Comment: Yes, pull requests are always from one branch to one other branch, not over a whole repository.