# Git how to overrride local repository with remote repository?

Tags: git, github

I want to overide my local project with an remote repository. So before I do something unedible, should I "just" do:

```
cd path/to/project
```

and then

```
git pull https://github.com/someuser/someproject.git
```

??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125968/how-do-i-force-git-pull-to-overwrite-local-files

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reset local repository branch to be just like remote repository HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628088/reset-local-repository-branch-to-be-just-like-remote-repository-head)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+local+repository+exactly+like+remote

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably `git reset --hard origin/HEAD` is what you need.  It will revert all changes not pushed to remote repository.

Comment: doesn't it need to be `origin/HEAD`? The OP seems to be asking how to ignore local changes and "overwrite" them with the upstream repo?

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you say override, this local project will be identical to remote repository?

If so,

How about go to a directory where you want to put it so cd path/to

Then,

git clone https://github.com/someuser/someproject.git

which will bring someproject into path/to. Fresh and new!

Answer (score 0):

There are some things you should check. So if you try to change your repo to a new one. You can go to your `.git/config` and change the path to the new repository. The repositories have to be identical.

Ich you have changed you can pull new changes from the new one with:

```
git pull origin branchname
```

Otherwise if you have local changes then you have to reset your branch first and then pull.

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

which reverts your changes to the last commit.