# git: undo all changes to my local repository and get a copy of upstream repository

Tags: git

I want to undo all my local changes and update my local machine with the code from git repository.

I have tried resetting the local branch by running the following commands:

```
git checkout 
git reset
```

When I run `git checkout` on local machine, it says:

> Your branch and 'origin/my-dev-environment' have diverged, and have 1
> and 26 different commits each, respectively.   (use "git pull" to
> merge the remote branch into yours)

If I try `git pull`, it would complain about conflicts:

> CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in template/myfile.cs Auto-merging
> pages/somefile.html

How can I clear all changes from my local repository and just get a copy of upsteam repository?

Answer (score 2):

This is explained here: [Reset local repository branch to be just like remote repository HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628088/reset-local-repository-branch-to-be-just-like-remote-repository-head)

```
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/master
```