# Cannot discard nor remove the mysterious file in Sourcetree

Tags: git, version-control, atlassian-sourcetree

[image: click to see the image]

I've been working on the project. In the middle of the day, this file had unknowingly popped up on the "Staged files". I couldn't do anything to it.

I checked in the explorer. This file was still there. It's a regular text file.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Here are what I've tried to solve the problem:

- reset the branch - hard
- stash the file
- use terminal
- checkout another branch and come back to the current branch

None of these worked.

Comment: The readme file is there in order to describe what your project is about. If you don't want it, you can unstage (`remove`) it.

Comment: I didn't do anything to it though. I also want to keep it that way. The program just popped it in the panel. If i commit the deletion and push, I will affect my teammate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reset local repository branch to be just like remote repository HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628088/reset-local-repository-branch-to-be-just-like-remote-repository-head)

Comment: Please don't put "Solved" in question and answer. We don't that here in Stack Overflow. Instead, click on the checkmark next to the answer. That will mark the answer as the one that solved the problem (will also show in green box in the question list). See [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This is the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628088/reset-local-repository-branch-to-be-just-like-remote-repository-head).

I use `git reset` on the terminal.

```
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/develop
```

then switched to another branch, then came back to develop again.

Comment: Please don't put "Solved" in question and answer. We don't that here in Stack Overflow. Instead, click on the checkmark next to the answer. That will mark the answer as the one that solved the problem (will also show in green box in the question list). See [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Faced same issue. I deleted the project in my local and I have cloned the same project freshly. it works.