# How to recover from detached (because of accidental pull)?

Tags: git

I created a commit and instead of pushing I ended up pulling from main, after that I got some conflicts and made another mistake by skipping the rebase.

My `git reflog` has this:

```
1cc9f3f (HEAD, main) HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from dabea28f2cce09575b49da21868098f4df8ebb94 to 1cc9f3f
dabea28 (origin/main, origin/HEAD) HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from main to dabea28
1cc9f3f (HEAD, main) HEAD@{2}: rebase finished: returning to refs/heads/main
1cc9f3f (HEAD, main) HEAD@{3}: commit: Merge?
cea642f HEAD@{4}: pull --progress --no-edit --no-stat --recurse-submodules=no origin: Version 2.33.1
dabea28 (origin/main, origin/HEAD) HEAD@{5}: pull --progress --no-edit --no-stat --recurse-submodules=no origin: checkout dabea28f2cce09575b49da21868098f4df8ebb94
4fc10c5 HEAD@{6}: commit: Support for multiple architectures.
96ca30f HEAD@{7}: reset: moving to HEAD
96ca30f HEAD@{8}: commit: Version 2.33.1
dabea28 (origin/main, origin/HEAD) HEAD@{9}: commit: Version 2.33
466448e HEAD@{10}: commit: Version 2.32
7d89f20 HEAD@{11}: commit: Version 2.31
```

I wanted go back to my changes that are available in `4fc10c5 HEAD@{6}` so that I can push to `main`. What do I do to undo these last changes and just continue pushing Head@{6}?

Basically, I lost all my changes after `HEAD@{5}`, when I `git pull` and `git rebase -skip` instead of `git push`.

I did copy all files manually by accessing the detached using `git checkout 4fc10c5`, just in case.

---

Status:

```
$ git status
On branch main
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/main' by 2 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

[image]

---

After `git reset --hard @{5}`:

```
7d89f20 (HEAD -> main) HEAD@{0}: reset: moving to @{5}
1cc9f3f HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from 4fc10c53d572616e4524f77d51a2cb556218bbbf to main
4fc10c5 HEAD@{2}: checkout: moving from 1cc9f3f80292dbd76e78f52cf8ea011cd4610801 to 4fc10c5
1cc9f3f HEAD@{3}: checkout: moving from dabea28f2cce09575b49da21868098f4df8ebb94 to 1cc9f3f
dabea28 (origin/main, origin/HEAD) HEAD@{4}: checkout: moving from main to dabea28
1cc9f3f HEAD@{5}: rebase finished: returning to refs/heads/main
1cc9f3f HEAD@{6}: commit: Merge?
cea642f HEAD@{7}: pull --progress --no-edit --no-stat --recurse-submodules=no origin: Version 2.33.1
dabea28 (origin/main, origin/HEAD) HEAD@{8}: pull --progress --no-edit --no-stat --recurse-submodules=no origin: checkout dabea28f2cce09575b49da21868098f4df8ebb94
4fc10c5 HEAD@{9}: commit: Support for multiple architectures.
96ca30f HEAD@{10}: reset: moving to HEAD
96ca30f HEAD@{11}: commit: Version 2.33.1
dabea28 (origin/main, origin/HEAD) HEAD@{12}: commit: Version 2.33
466448e HEAD@{13}: commit: Version 2.32
7d89f20 (HEAD -> main) HEAD@{14}: commit: Version 2.31
```

Comment: Please show us `git status`. And please explain what "push 4fc10c5 HEAD@{6} into main" means.

Comment: depending on the complexity of changes, a diff tool may be warranted.  you might be able to get away with stashing or exporting a patch.  i still prefer cloning a fresh copy over a fetch n reset https://stackoverflow.com/a/1628334/14237276

Comment: @Abel I can reset and just paste my changes back in, since I copied then to another folder. I just want to know if there's anyway to go back to `HEAD@{5}`, which is detached.

Comment: @matt Done, what happened was that after my accidental pull, I kind of lost my changes. The code is available at a detached head and I want to "revert" to before my accidental pull.

Answer (score 0):

> if there's anyway to go back to HEAD@{5}

You can reset your branch to that commit, and then push (this time)

```
git reset --hard @{5}
```

Check then first if what you see if what you had, before the pull (instead of push)

Comment: Didn't work, it reset to `HEAD@{11}` for some reason.

Comment: `$ git reset --hard @{5}`
`HEAD is now at 7d89f20 Version 2.31`

Comment: @NickeManarin What if you are using the `HEAD@{5}` SHA1 directly? `git reset --hard 4fc10c5 `

Comment: A `git rebase 4fc10c5` worked.

Comment: @NickeManarin I understand, but a reset should have worked too.

Answer (score 0):

Using `git rebase 4fc10c5` did the job.

[image]

Now I'm at pre-accidental-pull again.