# How can I recreate "git error fatal: Need to specify how to reconcile divergent branches."?

Tags: git

This question is *not* asking for how to fix this error, but how to recreate it in a local test repository, so I cam truly understand what this error actually means. I could not find a good explanation [HERE](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/14423#issuecomment-1105607066) or [HERE](https://discourse.getgrav.org/t/git-sync-you-have-divergent-branches-and-need-to-specify-how-to-reconcile-them/23809) or [HERE](https://www.cyberithub.com/solved-fatal-need-to-specify-how-to-reconcile-divergent-branches/) or [HERE](https://www.codinghelpsolutions.com/fatal-need-to-specify-how-to-reconcile-divergent-branches/). A way to recreate this error is described [HERE](https://www.reddit.com/r/git/comments/zcvrn9/you_have_divergent_branches_and_need_to_specify/) but this description is incomplete.

The reason I want to learn is that I had an issue with Git when I tried to update a local branch (the one one my local computer) from a remote repository (stored on some other computer). I tried to use the usual commands

```
git pull
git pull --ff-only
git reset --hard feature/branch
# <etc.>
```

And I also saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628088/reset-local-repository-branch-to-be-just-like-remote-repository-head) which did not help me.

It seems that a colleague did a force push to that branch, so that I had to reset my local branch(?). (I am not sure what that means actually.) Well, I tried to "reset" my local branch; see all the commands above and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628088/reset-local-repository-branch-to-be-just-like-remote-repository-head). But it did not work.

The solution finally was to do (when on that branch)

```
git reset --hard 6c3b91e   # <- a commit not in that branch ?????
git pull --ff-only
```

I asked the colleague what is going on, but he was unable to explain why I had to reset to a commit that wasn't even on the branch.

So therefore I want to recreate this situation myself with the idea to understand what was going on, to understand what is happening (in terms of branches, commits, index, HEAD, etc.) to better understand and learn how Git works.

Please refrain to suggest books or articles; they never explain any errors in a concise and clear way that I could possibly understand...

Interestingly, I was able to reproduce this error by making changed on `main` branch which I did not push to remote and then did a `git pull`. But first I was not on main branch when this error happened yesterday, and second, I was not interested in any changes on the branch at all. I wanted to make the branch locally equal to the branch as it was on the remote repository...

Comment: When you say "not on that branch" do you mean your local branch or the remote(-tracking) branch?

Comment: @knittl I mean that commit was not on that branch I was on. It was a commit on `main`.

Comment: And the remote history was rewritten. Why do you expect the commit to be in your local branch, that hasn't been rewritten?

Comment: @knittl I do not expect that change to be in my local branch just like that. That is why I was trying to checkout the local branch from the remote branch with all the history rewritten, so that my local branch is the same as the remote branch...

Comment: But you are not "checking out […] from the remote branch". You are not checking out anything and `git reset --hard feature/branch` resets to the local version of your branch. `feature/branch` is _not_ the remote-branch.

Comment: Also, `--ff-only` will fail as soon as the branches have diverged (have distinct local and remote commits). `--ff-only` will not work in the majority of cases (it only works when you do not have any local changes)

Comment: @knittl I did `git pull`? I usually do that on a branch and it "downloads" the changes made on that branch on the remote repo so the local branch and the remote branch are the same. Was I doing something wrong for 20 years???

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256326/discussion-between-alex-and-knittl).

Comment: Do you know what a "branch" is in Git? Do you know what "diverged branches" are? Do you know what `git pull` does under the hood? Do you know what a remote-tracking branch is? Do you understand how force-pushing affects other clones of the repo? Do you know what `reset --hard` does? Do you understand how commit ancestry works? Without clearing that up first, it's impossible to know what you are looking for in an answer.

Comment: I do not know these things in perfect details. As I said before, I am not a git expert.

Comment: @knittl Ok, I quickly got over these terms, which in most cases were explained by other terms, which I also had to look up. But I should be able to explain all these things to someone not familiar with git now (at least on very top level ...)

Answer (score 0):

It's really trivial to create "diverged" branches to show your issue. Error messages depend on your specific Git version and might also depend on local configuration.

```
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in ...
$ git config --unset pull.rebase
$ git config --unset pull.ff
$ cat > todos <<EOF
> my list
> EOF
$ git add todos
$ git commit -m 'initial todos'
[master (root-commit) e729989] initial todos
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 todos
$ git checkout -b original
Switched to a new branch 'original'
$ cat >> todos <<EOF
> 
> milk
> EOF
$ git add todos
$ git commit -m 'buy milk'
[original 8b36329] buy milk
 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+)
$ git checkout -b other
Switched to a new branch 'other'
$ sed -i 's/^milk$/eggs/' todos
$ git add todos
$ git commit --amend -m 'buy eggs' # this diverges the branches. there are other possibilities, including rebase and reset
[other a318636] buy eggs
 Date: Thu Dec 21 12:00:35 2023 +0100
 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+)
$ git checkout original
Switched to branch 'original'
$ git pull . other
From .
 * branch            other      -> FETCH_HEAD
hint: You have divergent branches and need to specify how to reconcile them.
hint: You can do so by running one of the following commands sometime before
hint: your next pull:
hint: 
hint:   git config pull.rebase false  # merge
hint:   git config pull.rebase true   # rebase
hint:   git config pull.ff only       # fast-forward only
hint: 
hint: You can replace "git config" with "git config --global" to set a default
hint: preference for all repositories. You can also pass --rebase, --no-rebase,
hint: or --ff-only on the command line to override the configured default per
hint: invocation.
fatal: Need to specify how to reconcile divergent branches.
$ git pull --ff-only . other
From .
 * branch            other      -> FETCH_HEAD
hint: Diverging branches can't be fast-forwarded, you need to either:
hint: 
hint:   git merge --no-ff
hint: 
hint: or:
hint: 
hint:   git rebase
hint: 
hint: Disable this message with "git config advice.diverging false"
fatal: Not possible to fast-forward, aborting.
$
```