# git command to move a folder inside another

Tags: git

I have created a folder `common` with a bunch of source files and folders.

Now I want to move the `common` folder into the `include` folder so it looks like `include/common`

I tried these:

1. `git add include`
2. `git mv common/ include/`

   but it fails with this error

   > fatal: bad source, source=myrepo/common, destination=myrepo/include
3. I tried `git mv common/ include/common` but I get the same error

Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 239, accepted):

One of the nicest things about git is that you don't need to track file renames explicitly. Git will figure it out by comparing the contents of the files.

So, in your case, don't work so hard: Ref: [Git mv docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-mv)

```
$ mkdir include
$ git mv common include
$ git rm -r common
$ git add include/common
```

Running `git status` should show you something like this:

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   renamed:    common/file.txt -> include/common/file.txt
#
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me (using Windows 7, 1.7.6.msysgit.0).  Git thinks old files were deleted and new files were added.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps git uses some external utility to determine file sameness taht doesn't work on Windows? This was a core piece of git's implementation.

Comment: @OliverF. Correction: `git mv` is equivalent.

Comment: Same error here trying to rename a folder called testes to tests, but in my case, is because I do have a branch named tests. I think git try to move all folder contents to tests branch. Renaming by hand works OK. Is this a bug?

Comment: @Bart try to git rm the old files/locations

Comment: `git log --follow somefile.txt` shows the correct log for files that have undergone a rename.

Comment: _"One of the nicest things about git "_ — one of the downsides of this nice feature is that it starts failing when you also modify the file that was renamed to a substantial extent, which causes it to see a deletion and addition of a new file, so frankly, I'd prefer explicit rename support instead.

Comment: If git converts line endings, this results in the problem described by @Bart. For this to work you have to do the following: git config --global core.autocrlf false

Comment: @ErikAllik Just do it int two separate commits and problem solved

Comment: Interesting, I have used that way and I had issues with reloading the moved projects. So not sure why, but I had to modify the *.sln file to point out the correct location of the moved project.

Comment: Doesn't it lose history then? (and first commit be that of the move)

Comment: @Bart Git may show the deletion and unstaged files, but once you stage both for the next commit, there's a good chance that it [shows the operation as rename](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67063342/1837006).

Answer (score 198):

```
 git mv common include
```

should work.

From the [`git mv` man page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-mv.html):

```
git mv [-f] [-n] [-k] <source> ... <destination directory>
```

> In the second form, the last argument has to be an existing directory; **the given sources will be moved into this directory**.
> The index is updated after successful completion, but the change must still be committed.

No "`git add`" should be done *before* the move.

---

Note: "`git mv A B/`", when `B` does not exist as a directory, should error out, but it didn't.

See [commit c57f628](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c57f6281ff847db7094d708f5c5b939d378f7120) by [Matthieu Moy (`moy`)](https://github.com/moy) for [Git 1.9/2.0](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b10cd577d8061912996576a096e2fd5503c770e6/Documentation/RelNotes/1.9.txt#L144-L146) (Q1 2014):

> Git used to trim the trailing slash, and make the command equivalent to '`git mv file no-such-dir`', which created the file `no-such-dir` (while the trailing slash explicitly stated that it could only be a directory).
>
> This patch skips the trailing slash removal for the destination path.
> The path with its trailing slash is passed to rename(2), which errors out with the appropriate message:

```
$ git mv file no-such-dir/
fatal: renaming 'file' failed: Not a directory
```

Answer (score 30):

Command:

```
$ git mv oldFolderName newFolderName
```

It usually works fine.

Error "bad source ..." typically indicates that after last commit there were some renames in the source directory and hence `git mv` cannot find the expected file.

The solution is simple - just commit before applying `git mv`.

Answer (score 25):

Make sure you have added all your changes to the staging area before running

```
git mv oldFolderName newFoldername
```

git fails with error

```
fatal: bad source, source=oldFolderName/somepath/somefile.foo, destination=newFolderName/somepath/somefile.foo
```

if there are any unadded files, so I just found out.

Answer (score 5):

Be careful doing

```
$ mkdir include
$ mv common include
$ git rm -r common
$ git add include/common
```

It may cause you will not see the git history of your project in new folder.

I tried

```
$ git mv oldFolderName newFolderName
```

got

```
fatal: bad source, source=oldFolderName/somepath/__init__.py, dest
ination=ESWProj_Base/ESWProj_DebugControlsMenu/somepath/__init__.py
```

I did

```
git rm -r oldFolderName
```

and

```
git add newFolderName
```

and I don't see old git history in my project. At least my project is not lost. Now I have my project in newFolderName, but without the history (

Just want to warn, be carefull using advice of "Andres Jaan Tack", if you dont want to lose your git hsitory.

Comment: Make sure all your changes have been added. Git fails saying "bad source" if there is unadded changes, so I just found out.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem with `git mv` where I wanted to move the contents of one folder into an existing folder, and ended up with this "simple" script:

```
pushd common; for f in $(git ls-files); do newdir="../include/$(dirname $f)"; mkdir -p $newdir; git mv $f $newdir/$(basename "$f"); done; popd
```

## Explanation

- **`git ls-files`**: Find all files (in the `common` folder) checked into git
- **`newdir="../include/$(dirname $f)"; mkdir -p $newdir;`**: Make a new folder inside the `include` folder, with the same directory structure as `common`
- **`git mv $f $newdir/$(basename "$f")`**: Move the file into the newly created folder

The reason for doing this is that git seems to have problems moving files into existing folders, and it will also fail if you try to move a file into a non-existing folder (hence `mkdir -p`).

The nice thing about this approach is that it *only* touches files that are already checked in to git. By simply using `git mv` to move an entire folder, and the folder contains unstaged changes, git will not know what to do.

After moving the files you might want to [clean the repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64966/6730769) to remove any remaining unstaged changes - just remember to dry-run first!

```
git clean -fd -n
```

Comment: Careful: if there is a space in your folder/file name this will give problems!

Answer (score 3):

Another way to move all files in a directory to a sub directory (keeps git history):

`$ for file in $(ls | grep -v 'subDir'); do git mv $file subDir; done;`

Comment: Careful: if there is a space in your folder/file name this will give problems!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [script](https://gist.github.com/mhamri/042fb3960e48eabd8fa277375a425c43).

```sh
# git mv a folder and sub folders in windows 

function Move-GitFolder {
    param (
        $target,
        $destination
    )
    
    Get-ChildItem $target -recurse |
    Where-Object { ! $_.PSIsContainer } |
    ForEach-Object { 
        $fullTargetFolder = [System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath((Join-Path (Get-Location) $target))
        $fullDestinationFolder = [System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath((Join-Path (Get-Location) $destination))
        $fileDestination = $_.Directory.FullName.Replace($fullTargetFolder.TrimEnd('\'), $fullDestinationFolder.TrimEnd('\'))

        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $fileDestination | Out-Null

        $filePath = Join-Path $fileDestination $_.Name

        git mv $_.FullName $filePath
        
    }
}
```

Usage

```
Move-GitFolder <Target folder> <Destination folder>
```

The advantage of this solution over other solutions is that it moves folders and files recursively and even creates the folder structure if it doesn't exist.

Comment: question not about windows and powershell

Answer (score 1):

### Move your files and use git stage

You **can** move your files using your favorite tools (command line, graphical file explorer) and git will figure out that you made move instead of deletion and creation **once you staged your operations**, as suggested by [@Andres](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3900841/1837006) but if you make too many modifications, as Erik Kaplun pointed out, explicit `git mv` could help.

#### Stage is not used in some applications

Some GUI git tools like GitHub Desktop does not provide direct access to stage: you can select and deselect modifications, but it does not modify the underlying git stage. You need to use a more powerful git tool, like the command-line tool or the authentic git GUI to stage the changes, then GitHub Desktop too will show the operation as rename.

Answer (score 1):

With `Git Tortoise` it is very easy.

Right drag source to destination ( select source, hold the right mouse key, drag to destination, release mouse ) .

A menu will be displayed which has `Git Move versioned items` and `Git Move and rename versioned items`.

Of course the git repo should be cloned locally

[image: Git move with git tortoise]

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, but in folder which I wanted to move I had files which I was not tracking.

let's say I had files

```
a/file1
a/untracked1
b/file2
b/untracked2
```

And I wanted to move only tracked files to subfolder `subdir`, so the goal was:

```
subdir/a/file1
subdir/a/untracked1
subdir/b/file2
subdir/b/untracked2
```

what I had done was:

- I created new folder and moved all files that I was interested in moving: `mkdir tmpdir && mv a b tmpdir`
- checked out old files `git checkout a b`
- created new dir and moved clean folders (without untracked files) to new subdir: `mkdir subdir && mv a b subdir`
- added all files from subdir (so Git could add only tracked previously files - it was somekind of `git add --update` with directory change *trick*): `git add subdir` (normally this would add even untracked files - this would require creating `.gitignore` file)
- `git status` shows now only moved files
- moved rest of files from tmpdir to subdir: `mv tmpdir/* subdir`
- `git status` looks like we executed `git mv` :)

Answer (score 0):

Another important note that I have missed, and fixed the "Bad Source" Error instantly:

(Just thought I will share my mistake just in case someone encounters it.. :))

Make sure the the correct path is selected in the git Console when you run the command:

```
- git mv Source Destination
```

If needed, use:

```
- cd SourceFolder
```

And then the mv command.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `GitLab`, its integrated Web-IDE, can be used for some file management tasks including move and rename ( without local clone )

Click on Web-IDE on the repository main window.

[image]

Right click on the folder and select `Rename/Move` ( for example moving `src` to `foo/bar/src`). The changes will be shown in the web-ide.

Remember to commit!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved this in Windows by:

1. Open the root directory in **Git Bash**
2. Type: `git mv -[options] soucse destination`
3. Check Status: `git status`

And everythig worked fine.

**Note: Use Git Bash not VS Code terminal etc.**

[git-mv - Move or rename a file, a directory, or a symlink](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-mv)

Answer (score -1):

I solved this on windows by doing this:

- Open Power shell console
- run dir
- Alt-click and drag over the file/folder name column, then copy
- Paste to notepad++
- run replace with regex: replace `(.*)` with `git mv ".\\\1" ".\\<New_Folder_Here>\"`
- copy all text from notepad++ into powershell
- hit enter

Answer (score -1):

I resolved this by using this command
mv <parent_folder/folder_to_move> <new_folder> while in the working directory of <new_folder>.
What this command does is rename the <folder_to_move> into the <new_folder> name. After which you can rename the target folder(folder_to_move) by using mv <new_folder>(formerly <folder_to_move>) <new_name_of_folder>

mv <new_folder> <new_name_of_folder>