# How to get rid of new files and file modifications in Git

Tags: git, github

So the situation is I cloned a repo from Github and I messed up trying to build it and it added new files and made changes to existing files in the repo. I have no commits and never staged anything. How do I revert to the clean master branch (meaning the actual local files on my PC) of the clone ?

If I wasn't using git commands I would delete the local files from disk and just re-download/clone the repo. However I feel there should be an easy way to do this using Git. I never messed with my Git settings, so git status still lists all untracked files and lists modifications, but I don't want to manually checkout every file one by one and then manually delete each untracked file one by one.

Comment: Related: [git reset --hard HEAD leaves untracked files behind](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327708/git-reset-hard-head-leaves-untracked-files-behind)

Comment: Yes, that's why you need to use the clean command too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```sh
git reset --hard # This resets all tracked files to default state
git clean -fd    # this clears working directory of all untracked files
```

It may be obvious, but please use this commands with caution. They are
destructive and will delete your work without asking.

`git reset` resets current HEAD to default state. The `--hard` specifies the
hard mode, which deletes all the changes. You can also use it with `--soft`
mode, which just resets everything else to specified commit, but keeps all your
changes, and `--mixed` mode, which makes all your changes unstaged. However,
this command only works on the tracked files.

`git clean` cleans the folder of untracked files. `-d` option makes it work on
directories as well as files (please note that git only tracks files — it
doesn't that notice folders exist unless you put something in them), and `-f`
option is a simple fuse — it wont work without it (unless your repo is
configured otherwise). However, this command still ignores files specified in
.gitignore, unless you add `-x` flag.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

`HEAD` -> refers to the commit that you started with, before you started making changes (as Simon points out in the comments, it is the last commit that was checked out).

`reset --hard` -> changes the files in your working directory to match that commit, disregarding any changes that are presently there

You can also use `reset --hard` to move to different commits, tags, or branches by doing `git reset --hard branch-name`

Comment: HEAD refers to the last checkout commit

Comment: I think that HEAD is not neccessary in this case.

Comment: It's not, but I find it's a bit more declarative for someone just learning.

Comment: And yes, I think Simon's terminology is a little better here. "Last checked out commit" makes more sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simply: `git reset --hard`

You may need to delete added file manually.

Answer (score 0):

to remove all local changes

```
git checkout -- .
```

if you have added files you want to remove too

```
git clean
```

I suggest using githug to start learning git, it makes learning more of a game

https://github.com/Gazler/githug