# Removing everything locally to last commit?

Tags: git

Ok, so I am new to git and scared to do anything that would permanently mess things up. I did a commit yesterday, then pulled from the remote repo, and have messed around on some of the files. Now I want to go back to everything I had right after I committed and before I pulled, but I want to make sure that I don't mess up anything on the remote branch, and dont want to lose anything that I committed. What should I do? I know there are a lot of questions like this, but I wanted to ask specifically for what I am trying to do. Also, once I get back to the last commit, can I just pull again from the remote branch?

Comment: Delete everything and clone again

Comment: Try `git ref-log`.  You should be able to see your commit.  reset your  repository to that commit.

Comment: @sleepyhead: if user3507586 deletes everything, their commit will be lost.

Comment: how do I reset my repository to that commit? git ref-log is not a command. did you mean reflog or log?

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't want to mess anything locally, you could simply duplicate (copy) your entire repo in a new folder, and try that in said new folder.

---

> I dont want to lose anything that I committed

First, make a branch where you are (that will references your last commmits)

```
 git branch tmp
```

From "[HEAD and ORIG_HEAD in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/964927/6309)":

> "`pull`" or "`merge`" always leaves the original tip of the current branch in `ORIG_HEAD`.

```
git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD
```

If you did any more merge after the pull, then ORIG_HEAD wouldn't have the right information anymore, and you would have to get the commit before the pull in the [`git reflog`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog).

> I want to make sure that I don't mess up anything on the remote branch, and

The [`git reset`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) is a local command applied to your local clone: the remote repo isn't aware of it.

Once you have reset, you can [`git cherry-pick`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) the last few commits you see with `git log tmp`.

Comment: may I ask what the difference is between HEAD and ORIG_HEAD?

Comment: @user3507586: http://stackoverflow.com/a/967611/6309 "`ORIG_HEAD` is previous state of `HEAD`, set by commands that have possibly dangerous behavior, to be easy to revert them".

Comment: okay, what I did was 'git reset --hard 8b22b3b' which reset to that commit I think? but when I run 'git status' I see a bunch of untracked files and I'm no sure where they came from. Is this normal?

Comment: @user3507586 yes, it is: see the comment of http://stackoverflow.com/q/4327708/6309 (and its answer) Again making a copy of the repo *before* those commands is a good idea.