# git is not deleting files in the directory?

Tags: git

So I made a new git branch, did some things, added some files, tested some other things.

Decided I didn't want any of those changes so I committed on the new branch and then deleted it thinking that git would delete everything that was done in that new branch.

I switched back to my master and some of the files in the branch directory were still there.

The revisions of other files returned to their pre-branched state which is good but I am still left with a fair bit of folder garbage that is left over.

I tried doing a...

```
git reset --hard oldcommit
```

but that did not cause the files to be removed either.
How can I make git remove these files?

Comment: Have you tried git rm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git reset --hard HEAD leaves untracked files behind](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327708/git-reset-hard-head-leaves-untracked-files-behind)

Comment: I know I can manually remove them with git-rm, but what if I don't want to manually remove tons of files, there should be a way for git to delete them automatically, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to "clean" the working directory and the index from all the content that you did not commit

You can do it with:

```
rm <any leftovers>
git clean -Xfd // Capital X
git clean -xfd // small x
```

---

Here are some more advanced options:

Several options:

1. #### Git reset to a given commit

   ```
   # This will destroy any local modifications.
   # Don't do it if you have uncommitted work you want to keep.
   git reset --hard 0d1d7fc32
   ```
2. #### checkout the last desired

   ```
   git checkout -b <new_branch> <commit id>

   // Now your branch contains all the commits up to the 
   // desired one and without the newer ones
   ```
3. #### `git revert`

   git revert will allow you to rollback any commit, what you need to do is to make a list of all the commits in A which you want to remove (with script) and then revert them from the second repository

   ```
   git revert <commit1> <commit2> ... <commitn>
   ```
4. #### `filter-branch`

   Use this option to completely remove the commits from the history.

   ```
   git filter-branch --commit-filter '
       if [ `git rev-list --all --grep "<log-pattern>" | grep -c "$GIT_COMMIT"` -gt 0 ]
       then
           skip_commit "$@";
       else
           git commit-tree "$@";
       fi'  
   HEAD
   ```