# git alias for a full reset to HEAD

Tags: git, git-alias

I have the following git aliases:

```
[alias]
        b           = branch
        p           = push
        co          = checkout
        cm          = commit -m
        cmall       = !git add -A && git commit -m
        cob         = checkout -b
        cached      = diff --cached
        addall      = add -A
        editconfig  = config --global -e
        save        = !git add -A && git commit -m SAVEPOINT
        unsave      = reset HEAD~1 --mixed
        amend       = commit -a --amend
        wipe        = !git add -A && git commit -qm 'WIPE SAVEPOINT' && git reset HEAD~1 --hard
        reset       = !git reset --hard HEAD && git clean -qfdx
```

`reset` should actually reset, but as is still leaves untracked files.

based on [git reset --hard HEAD leaves untracked files behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327708/git-reset-hard-head-leaves-untracked-files-behind), the second part of my `reset` should work, in fact it does when I do it alone...which makes me thing there's error in my gitconfig syntax. Why isn't reset working? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`git-config` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config): "To avoid confusion and troubles with script usage, aliases that hide existing git commands are ignored."

So your `reset` alias is being ignored and the original reset command is run. You'll have to name the alias something else.

Answer (score 1):

Or maybe there is a way! *Mhwuahahaha*

http://blogs.atlassian.com/2014/10/advanced-git-aliases/

`my_alias = "!f() { 〈your complex command〉 }; f"`