# How to reset Git repo to HEAD?

Tags: git

I have changed and added a couple of files within my project for test purposes and now I am trying to reset the entire project to last commit I did. Hence, I want to reset to HEAD. So I did:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

So now, all the files I changed are reset to the version I had at my last commit, but the problem is, that all the new files I created still remain. Shouldn't in reset process all be reset to exactly the version of in this case HEAD?

How can I properly set everything in my project to the state of the HEAD as if I didn't change anything?

Comment: Did you research this at all? I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327708/git-reset-hard-head-leaves-untracked-files-behind more or less immediately

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove any untracked files, run

```
git clean -df
```

(`-d` removes directories, `-f` means "force" - without it, nothing is removed.)

You can also add `-x` to remove ignored files (see `git help clean`).