# Git checkout issues

Tags: git, svn

I would like to perform something similar to an `svn update` operation with `git`. I have a remote repository which originates from a fork operation on a master repository. I cloned this remote repository and now have a local repository.

I started working in this local repository and modified some files, added some files and deleted some files. I have committed/staged nothing at this point. I would like to come up with a generic command which will allow me to revert the state of my local repository to how it is in my remote forked repository, but without deleting the files I added. More specifically, the operation (similar to an `svn update` should:

- Revert all modified files to how they are in the remote repository
- Add all files in remote repository which are deleted in local repository
- Leave newly added files alone.

I thought that this was within the realm of the `git checkout`. When I run `git checkout` it shows that the files are added, deleted or modified, but when I run a `git status` again I get the same as what I got before running `git checkout`. Also browsing through my local repo I see that that deleted files are not added again.

Am I using `git checkout` wrong? Why doesn't my local repo go back to what it was before?

Comment: Are you referring to a fork such as github's "fork"  Git itself doesn't implement a feature called fork.

Comment: why can't use the git pull origin command for the update.git checkout is like switching the branch not for svn update.

Answer (score 1):

If you have not yet staged the new files, the files are untracked. Untracked files will not be removed when resetting. You can reset using:

```
git reset master --hard
```

Please note hard resetting can be a little scary, make real sure you have no tracked changes you wish to keep!

See also:
[git reset --hard HEAD leaves untracked files behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327708/git-reset-hard-head-leaves-untracked-files-behind)

Comment: Its scary if you have tracked changes you care about. For now I am still useless with git so I'm not making any commits/staging. So actually `git reset master --hard` is exactly what I need...

Comment: Actually what does `master` stand for ? Is it my forked repository or the main repository?

Comment: @user32882: `master` is a branch name. Your branch names are *yours* to do with as you will. What you need to know here ... well, there's a LOT :-) but you can start with this concept: a commit has a unique hash ID, across every repository everywhere. If you have that hash ID you have that commit. If Bob has the hash ID he has the commit too. Everyone with *that* ID has *that* commit. No other commit has the same ID, no matter who makes it where, everyone agrees on the hash ID. Meanwhile a branch *name* like `master` is *yours*, and what it does is to remember *one* hash ID for you!

Comment: @user32882: hash IDs are big and ugly and impossible for humans to deal with, which is why we use names: branch names like `master` or tag names like `v2.1`. They remember the hash IDs for us. The thing about branch names is that when you `git clone` someone else's repository, your Git *changes* their branch names, so that they won't conflict with your names. So Bob's `master` is your `bob/master`, for instance.

Comment: @user32882: `git reset` does *three* things: (1) changes the hash ID stored in one of your branch names. (2) resets what Git calls the *index*, which is the set of files that go into the *next* commit. (3) resets what Git calls the *work-tree*, which is the only place you can see and work with your files.

Comment: Thanks a lot @torek. Quite a lot for my small brain to handle but very educational. I will have to read and reread your comments to fully understand :). I am sure they will also be helpful to others in the same spot...