# Git Reset --hard leaves newly added files

Tags: git

I have used `git reset --hard` however it has left files the were just created and not committed. Is that by design? Is there an easy way to clear all these files as well?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git reset --hard HEAD leaves untracked files behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327708/git-reset-hard-head-leaves-untracked-files-behind)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git reset --hard` changes all files in the index, but not the untracked files, as you noticed.

You can use (note: DANGEROUS because irreversible. Removed files cannot be recovered.):

```
git clean -dfx
```

if you want to remove all untracked files. The options:

- `-d` : remove directories as well
- `-f` : force = really remove (when you leave out this flag, it is a "dry-run")
- `-x` : remove also files ignored by `.gitignore`

Answer (score 2):

> Is that by design?

Yes.

> Is there an easy way to clear all these files as well?

```
git clean -fd
```