# Why do I receive the error "Untracked working tree file" when switching branches in Git?

Tags: git

Until yesterday my project has only a branch with a .gitignore file similar to:

```
*.log
upload/*
!upload/global/empty.txt
```

It worked fine until I added a new branch and changed this .gitignore to not ignore upload files. The new .gitignore file remained with only one line:

```
*.log
```

I returned to *master* branch without problems, but now each time I want to go to the new branch I receive a message like this:

> error: Untracked working tree file 'upload/file.txt' would be
>   overwritten by merge.

I need to checkout this branch to work with it or, at least, rescue the commits I made.

Note: I've found this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858047/error-the-following-untracked-working-tree-files-would-be-overwritten-by-checko), but doesn't answer my question.

Comment: So you removed the line `*.log` from your `.gitignore` file, in your new branch?  And you still have `upload/*` in the `.gitignore' file in both branches?

Comment: No, I removed the "upload/*" and "!upload/global/empty.txt" lines

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your issue is that in the new branch you are not tracking `upload/file.txt` but you are tracking it in your master branch. So when you switch to your new branch, your version, from master, will overwrite the untracked file.

Add the `-f` flag, to your [git checkout](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-checkout), to force git to overwrite the untracked file.

Comment: It works, I'm able to change branches. But it gives a list of errors "unable to unlink" for each file in the *upload* folder. Git status says "nothing to commit" in both branches. Is possible to avoid this errors or should I live with it? :)