# I can't checkout other branch in git

Tags: xcode, git

## Error

I got error

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
MyProject/xcuserdata/shingo.nakanishi.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate
Please move or remove them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
```

### I try this

([The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858047/error-the-following-untracked-working-tree-files-would-be-overwritten-by-checko))

```
git rm --cached MyProject/xcuserdata/shingo.nakanishi.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate
```

and

`git clean -d -fx ""`

`git commit -a`

`git push`

When 「UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate」file is not exist, **this is work**

### But Xcode soon make UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate.

When I use Xcode, Xcode make UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate file.

So, Each checkout branch , I must do `git clean -d -fx ""` each Time.

### My ~/.gitignore

this is my ~/.gitignore

```
.DS_Store
*UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate
*Breakpoints.xcbkptlist
```

**How to ignore the file?**

Answer (score 0):

the first error means it is already in your repository (committed). you need to first remove it from the repository, then ignore it.

Comment: I'm sory, I forgot write `git commit -a` and `git push`. I think the file deleted from repository

Answer (score 0):

please read [Git ignore file for Xcode projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49478/git-ignore-file-for-xcode-projects)

https://gist.github.com/3786883

Please search the SO before post questions.

For the change you have made. use `git checkout -- <fileName>` to discard changes.

Answer (score 0):

Git doesn't ignore the files you already tracked. So just remove that file from git first

```
git rm -rf file 
git commit -m "remove"
git push origin #{branchname}
```

and after, you're .gitignore will ignore it :)

Comment: `git rm -rf file` fatal: pathspec 'file' did not match any files. I have have difficulty.

Comment: you must change "file" to MyProject/xcuserdata/shingo.nakanishi.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate , or how you'r file is actually called .