# git reset HEAD@{1} not removing files that were added?

Tags: git, github, git-pull

does `git reset HEAD@{1}` not remove files that were added from `git pull`?

What I did. I used `git pull`. Got newest source code. Then found out that code was not good and wanted to restore my code to previous state, so I did `git reset HEAD@{1}`. It restored back.

But now if I try to do `git pull` again I will get such error:

`error: Untracked working tree file 'addons/auth_crypt/i18n/fr_CA.po' would be overwritten by merge.  Aborting`

If I rename that file, it throws another same error for another file, that I guess was added on pull before doing git reset. So do I need to remove/rename such files manually and only then I will be able to do `git pull`. Or is there easier fix (there could be hundreds of such files)?

I also tried `git pull --rebase`, but get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two files within the same path. One locally and one remote tracked. If you pull your remote tracked would overwrite your local file. That's what git is claiming. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17404316/the-following-untracked-working-tree-files-would-be-overwritten-by-merge-but-i) are further informations available.

Another problem: If you pull again you have the same code contained again that you tried to avoid by using `git reset HEAD@{1}` because that command didn't change your remote branch.

Comment: When I did git pull second time, I actually wanted same code that was when I did first pull, because I checked and now I saw that remote code was OK to be used. Thanks for the link, it solved my problem.