# How to pull repository to my remote server?

Tags: github, ssh, remote-server

I have created a Django project and now I want to pull it to my remote server.

What I did so far:

- I already pushed local project to Github.
- I have followed the whole guide https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-20-04
- My remote project has same names of files as the local one. When I try to `git pull origin master` I get this msg:

`error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge: xxxx Please move or remove them before you merge.`

What should I do? I guess this occurs because the files have the same name, but it's ok. I want to pull the content from one to another.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep them, [as mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26639255/6309):

```sh
git add .  (., not *)
git stash
git pull
```

But if you want a clean workspace: `git clean -ndxf` (remove `-n` when you are OK with the preview output listing what would be removed)

Only when you have a clean workspace will you be able to pull.