# how to undo git add* git stash git pull?

Tags: git, github

Hy guys!I am working on a project and when i wanted to pull the code prom gitHub i runned git stash/ git pull and an this occurred "the following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge",and after that I executed the commands git add*/git stash/git pull and all the files that i worked on dissapeared. How can i restore them ?I did exactly what the first comment said [The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge, but I don't care](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17404316/the-following-untracked-working-tree-files-would-be-overwritten-by-merge-but-i) .Thank you !

Comment: You can get back your stashed changes by `git stash pop`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to recover stashed uncommitted changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19003009/how-to-recover-stashed-uncommitted-changes)

Comment: Did you literally run `git add*` (no space between `add` and `*`), or `git add *`? If you did the latter, are you on Windows using CMD.EXE, or are you using a Unix-like shell?