# Restoring deleted directories and files in git

Tags: git

I was pulling down recent changes to a repository and I ran into the situation where I encountered the following error:

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge
```

I looked at the following thread: [untracked working tree files would be overwritten](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858047/error-the-following-untracked-working-tree-files-would-be-overwritten-by-checko)

and decided (foolishly without reading entirely what it did) to execute the following command:

```
git clean  -d  -fx ""
```

This proceeded to delete directories and proceeded to break my project. Is there any way to retrieve these directories (some of which may be untracked)?

Comment: Through git, no, but there is software to recover deleted files that may help in this situation.  Actual answer will depend on your OS, but here's an example for [Linux](http://superuser.com/questions/150027/how-to-recover-a-removed-file-under-linux) and [Windows](http://superuser.com/questions/449550/how-do-i-recover-or-undelete-files-that-i-accidentally-deleted).

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to have to go with "no."  My sympathies.  git will not, ever, delete content for tracked files, so *everything* it deleted was untracked, but if you have no other retrieval method, they're gone.