# error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge: .gitignore

Tags: git

I am working on a web app with Angular JS. After Commit, I am trying to Pull the latest version of the other web developer to merge it with mine before I Push my latest changes.
I am getting this error and don't know why is this happening because I had no problem on the previous pull / push.

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
.gitignore
Please move or remove them before you can merge.
```

Comment: This means someone has added a `.gitignore` to the repo you are pulling. If you were to merge, your local `.gitignore` would be overwritten and lost forever.

Comment: `git` is also unable to merge your changes to `.gitignore` in, so merge them manually.

Comment: You can A) just delete your local copy and perform the merge, or B) commit your local copy and then handle the conflict on merge

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858047/git-error-the-following-untracked-working-tree-files-would-be-overwritten-by-ch)

Answer (score 5):

It appears you have created a local `.gitignore` file but have not commited it to the repository and the remote you are attempting to interact with (pull/push) now has a `.gitignore`. This would be the case for any file in your repo when this happens

Since `.gitignore` is not just any file, it affects the way git behaves, I would compare the two manually, create a file that is a union of the two, commit it and then merge, fixing any formatting issues that might exist.

These could be the exact same file, but `git` wouldn't know because you haven't added it locally. This isn't a file you want to be changing often because it can make checkouts behave differently.

Github maintains [a list of useful `.gitignore` templates](https://github.com/github/gitignore) for most languages.