# error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout

Tags: git, git-pull, git-status

When I do `git status` it says `nothing to commit, working directory clean`

And then I do `git pull --rebase`, it says:

```
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
    includes/resources/moduledata/12/_Fr4_02_Invention_IPA_SR_la-Fête.pdf
Please move or remove them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
could not detach HEAD
```

Similar error when doing `git pull origin master`

```
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
    includes/resources/moduledata/12/_Fr4_02_Invention_IPA_SR_la-Fête.pdf
Please move or remove them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

My `.gitignore` file:

```
→ cat .gitignore 
.htaccess
bower_components/
```

This file has been coming up constantly and when I remove it from file system, git will say I removed this file, while in the other messages, it says it is untracked. How could it be untracked and tracked at the same time?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Without a complete picture of the repo, what follows is more of a guess than anything else, but it might explain the situation. Let's say your history looks as follows:

```
A -- C [origin/master]
  \ 
   B [HEAD, master]
```

You write:

> This file has been coming up constantly and when I remove it from file system, git will say I removed this file, while in the other messages, it says it is untracked.

I'm guessing you may have run

```
git rm --cached <file-in-question>
```

and committed that deletion in commit `B`; therefore, the file is no longer tracked in your local repo and but it's still present in your working tree.

In the meantime, the upstream branch received commit `C` from one of your collaborators, in which `<file-in-question>` was *not* removed from version control. What you're attempting to effect with

```
git pull --rebase
```

is something like this:

```
 A -- C [origin/master]
       \ 
        B' [HEAD, master]
```

However, as the message says,

> The [...] untracked working tree [file] would be overwritten by checkout

Indeed, rewinding commit `C` (in order to replay `B` on top of it) would result in the revision of `<file-in-question>` (from commit `C`) to be checked out in your working tree, in which an untracked file of the same name already exists. The contents of that untracked file may be valuable; you may not want that file to be overwritten by a another version of it. Therefore, Git stops in its track and tells you what's wrong.

**Edit**: Here is a baby example that reproduces the situation...

```sh
cd ~/Desktop
mkdir test
cd test
git init
touch README.md
git add README.md
git commit -m "add README"

# simulate a remote branch moving ahead by one commit
# (that doesn't remove the README)
git checkout -b origin_master
printf "This is a README.\n" > README.md
git add README.md
git commit -m "add description in README"

# remove the README and create a new commit on master
git checkout master
git rm --cached README.md
git commit -m "remove README"

# simulate an attempt to rebase master to its "upstream" branch, origin_master
git rebase --onto origin_master master
```

That last command spews out the following:

```
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
    README.md
Please move or remove them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
could not detach HEAD
```

I suggest you run

```
git fetch
git log --stat origin/master..master -- <file-in-question>
```

to check whether something like that happened.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I posted the question right before I got off work. Thanks for the extremely detailed answer. But unfortunately the `git log` doesn't return anything for that file. I'm wondering if it's an encoding error caused by the french character. I copied the file name from log over and it shows up like this: `→ git log --stat origin/master..master includes/resources/moduledata/12/_Fr4_02_Invention_IPA_SR_la-Fe<0302>te.pdf`.

Comment: No problem; if you like it, upvote it `:)` I'm guessing the reason `git log` doesn't output anything is that accented e. You need to use the actual extended-ASCII chararacter: `ê`.

Comment: I never found out what's causing it. My coworker has removed the file from the depository and eventually solved the problem. Thank you for the help.

Comment: `git rm --cached <file-in-question>` worked indeed. After some careful pulling, checkouts and merging all was fixed.

Comment: What you are saying happened is exactly what happend to me. I used `git rm --cached <File>` and now I can't checkout without deleting it. Do you have a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 39):

This could also happen due to a case change on the filename.  I had the same problem and this is what solved it for me.

```
git config core.ignorecase true
```

True for Mac or PC.

Alternative solutions at:  [The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858047/git-error-the-following-untracked-working-tree-files-would-be-overwritten-by-ch)

Comment: This did it for me. I had a messages.properties that I wanted to pull and had a local Messages.properties (dunno why, they were generated). So check if such a file that differs only by upper or lowercase exists and if so execute the above command.

Comment: Thank you it was the case for me too! it solved the problem

Answer (score 7):

**Remove all untracked files (carefull):**

```
git clean  -d  -fx ""
```

Comment: I still get an error: `Cannot rebase: Your index contains uncommitted changes.
Please commit or stash them.`

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky  this is to remove untracked files not changed files, for changed files you need to do "git stash" and then execute other commands

Comment: @AbhishekGoel - I tried this command and it gave me the following error

`fatal: empty string is not a valid pathspec. please use . instead if you meant to match all paths`

Changing to `git clean  -d  -fx .` worked, thanks

Answer (score 0):

For me this was a version of filename case mismatch, as mentioned by [@MikeHall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2213833/mikehall).
But in order to fix it I actually needed to amend the most recent commit with the "bad" filenames to their "correct" case.  Then after that I was able to successfully rebase beyond that problematic commit.