# can't checkout branch due to hidden untracked files

Tags: android, git

Two files `:ls` and `:ls.pub` were removed with `git rm`

and my branch is clean

```
C:\dev\myApp>git status
On branch myApp-branch
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/myApp-branch'.
```

but when I switch branches, I am getting this error

```
C:\dev\myApp>git checkout myApp-branch2
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
:ls
:ls.pub
Please move or remove them before you switch branches.
Aborting
```

I couldn't find the files anywhere locally or on the repo

Comment: If you removed files(using `rm -rf <FIles>`) and git still see them it's because they auto generate themselves nut you can use `.gitignore` || `git stash` for not having issues with that files

Comment: The files still exist in *some other* commit; checking out that *other* commit would—because `git checkout` means *remove these files, check out those other files instead* —have to remove your *current* `:ls` and `:ls.pub` files. [Related.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25392771/1256452)

Comment: The thing *I* find confusing is that Windows in general won't allow files with colon in the names, so there should not *be* a `:ls` or `:ls.pub` file in your working tree.

Comment: @torek this smells like the issue with files having a space at the end of the name, which was also not technically allowed by Windows, but worked anyway.