# Resolving Conflict using Git in VS2013

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, azure-devops

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and Git on VSO.  I have some changes locally that I want to push but the incomming changes have some conflicts.  [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd286559.aspx) article has an example of a "Resolve the conflicts" dialog but that is not showing up in my version of VS103.  Right now, I have a deadlock.

[image]

Do I need to use an external git command?  It seems that I should be able to stay within VS to do this, as it is a common use case.

Comment: The difftool and mergetools provided with visual studio are quite poor. Install WinMerge and KDiff3 and configure KDiff3 as your mergetool.

Comment: I am starting to learn that.  I think it is this issue that VS can't handle: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858047/git-error-the-following-untracked-working-tree-files-would-be-overwritten-by-ch

Comment: I would recomment using GitExtensions for working with Git repositories on Windows. The Visual Studio views are really organised around how TFS works and do not present git information all that well. VS's git support is fully compatible with all other git clients so you can use any tool you are comfortable with.

Comment: May be this question can help -
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27458236/visual-studio-2013-does-not-offer-to-do-merge-on-git-pull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on patthoyts suggestion, I installed git extensions.  Much better than the built in tools for VS and I solved my problem.  Thanks.

Comment: which extension did you use?

Comment: Yes, would you please say which extensions ?

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to [VS 2013 Update 4](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2994375).

This is a bug in VS, being triggered by having files in your repository that have line endings committed that do not match your `core.eol` or `.gitattributes` configuration.

While you should [consider canonicalizing your line endings](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/) so that they exist in your repository the way they are configured, since you may have other strange errors with git clients in the future, this particular bug is fixed in VS 2013 Update 4.

Comment: Oh?  What does `git status` report?  What is shown in the Team Explorer changes page?