# Git marks file as deleted but also as untracked

Tags: git, github

In a feature branch of a repository I get mixed messages from git:

```
λ git status
On branch feature/****
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/feature/****'.
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)

        deleted:    path/to/file/abc.tf

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        path/to/file/abc.tf

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

This file is tracked (and should be) by the remote repository.

How do I resolve these messages so that `git status` gives me no changes or untracked files?

- I have tried to `git pull` -> nothing happens.
- I have tried a clean install `git clone` -> Same messages
- I have tried to remove abc.tf from the directory and then `git checkout -f` -> back to where I started.
- I have tried `git reset --hard HEAD` -> nothing happens.
- I have **not** tried commiting the file again, because I would rather not if I can resolve in localy. But maybe that is the only solution?
- abc.tf is not in my .gitignore

I usually work on linux and these messages dont show there, only on Windows (although I havent tried a clean install on Linux).

Bonus points if you can tell me why this is happening and how to avoid it.

Comment: What does `git checkout path/to/file/abc.tf` result in? If it's  `error: pathspec 'path/to/file/abc.tf' did not match any file(s) known to git.` the most likely the repo is corrupt .

Comment: @Dom I did get that message. And I assume that the remote repository is corrupt aswell. To fix the issue I had to 1: remove abc.tf from the repository. 2: `git add -u` to stage the delete. 3: Put abc.tf back where it was. 4: `git add .`, by now a `git status` said that I had performed a rename of abc.tf to the exact same name. 5: commit and push. If you know why this happens then please post an aswer, otherwise i'll just post my steps to resolve it. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still do not know why this happened, but presumebly the remote branch has been corrupted somehow, here is how I solved it:

1. remove abc.tf from the repository.
2. `git add -u` to stage the delete.
3. Put abc.tf back where it was.
4. `git add .`, by now a git status said that I had performed a rename of abc.tf to the exact same name.
5. `commit and push`

Answer (score 1):

You didn't post the *real* file name, but I suspect that what happened is that the files differed only by case (that is, capital/lower-case).  [I've seen this kind of problem before on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25384632/5486), because Git considers files that differ by case as different files, but Windows doesn't.

One thing to try, if possible, is to check out a version of the project before that file existed, and then check out the current version (after the casing was changed).

Comment: I know this is a long time ago now, but I remember trying yor suggestion and I remember that it did not help me solve my problem. The problem did not arrise from different casings on the file name (as I could see back then). Still, I found your answer helpful, and maybe it will solve a similar problem for someone else.
PS. sorry I took forever to answer