# My unity project asset files have deleted when using git? How to get back to my original project?

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, git-bash

I just set up Git for Unity and am using Git Bash for commands.

I've made 2 commits for testing purposes by creating a `readme.txt` in the Unity project folder.

And I've added all files to staging area by `git add`. Then I've closed my Unity editor.

All scripts and asset files are gone!

I have the commit IDs of both as follows:

```
adc05927e23b8316806bb4f6939753bd9ce88bbf second
02c633eb3dca0bd23c96c1a6fde4f21e091837a9 first
```

My git status now:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        .gitignor.txt
        Assets/
        Library/
        ProjectSettings/
        UnityPackageManager/
        reset.exe.stackdump

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Please help. I don't have any backup!

This is my 3rd commit ID:
    9bd4cdef5fd52edc4fb1c3b8bee83f8b0d888d0c

When I'm trying to checkout this, it shows this error:

```
git checkout 9bd4cdef5fd52edc4fb1c3b8bee83f8b0d888d0c
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:

    Assets/Resources.meta
    Assets/Script.meta
    Assets/Shader.meta
    Library/AnnotationManager
    Library/AssetImportState
    Library/BuildPlayer.prefs
    Library/BuildSettings.asset
    Library/CurrentLayout.dwlt
    Library/EditorUserBuildSettings.asset
    Library/EditorUserSettings.asset
    Library/InspectorExpandedItems.asset
    Library/LastSceneManagerSetup.txt
    Library/LibraryFormatVersion.txt
    Library/MonoManager.asset
    Library/ProjectSettings.asset
    Library/ScriptAssemblies/BuiltinAssemblies.stamp
    Library/ScriptMapper
    Library/ShaderCache.db
    Library/ShaderCache/1/169785a86726a82ea70eb9234fb30234.bin
    Library/ShaderCache/2/2506cc1744df364cfed92d3305f307dc.bin
    Library/ShaderCache/3/303cafc81dadaed5bb0d6944d29972b0.bin
    Library/ShaderCache/3/3d3ae902e0c3bf89c784c0f0e22fd76e.bin
    Library/ShaderCache/4/4e40a25a1b78714dcf9d9b46460ad876.bin
    Library/ShaderCache/5/5fc1a73df3e7412b1918712426388655.bin
    Library/ShaderCache/8/82ad14a10b072134a00f2efbbcdd9505.bin
    Library/ShaderCache/9/919876937b76b8a0851cc42257a676dd.bin
    Library/SpriteAtlasDatabase.asset
    Library/TilemapEditorUserSettings.asset
    Library/assetDatabase3
    Library/expandedItems
    Library/metadata/00/00000000000000001000000000000000
    Library/metadata/00/00000000000000001000000000000000.info
    Library/metadata/00/00000000000000002000000000000000
    Library/metadata/00/00000000000000002000000000000000.info
    Library/metadata/00/00000000000000003000000000000000
    Library/metadata/00/00000000000000003000000000000000.info
    Library/metadata/00/00000000000000004000000000000000
    Library/metadata/00/00000000000000004000000000000000.info
    Library/metadata/00/00000000000000004100000000000000
    Library/metadata/00/00000000000000004100000000000000.info
    Library/metadata/00/00000000000000005000000000000000
    Library/metadata/00/00000000000000005000000000000000.info
    Library/metadata/00/00000000000000005100000000000000
    Library/metadata/00/00000000000000005100000000000000.info
    Library/metadata/00/00000000000000006000000000000000
    Library/metadata/00/00000000000000006000000000000000.info
    Library/metadata/00/00000000000000006100000000000000
    Library/metadata/00/00000000000000006100000000000000.info
    Library/metadata/00/00000000000000007000000000000000
    Library/metadata/00/00000000000000007000000000000000.info
    Library/metadata/00/00000000000000007100000000000000
    Library/metadata/00/00000000000000007100000000000000.info
    Library/metadata/00/00000000000000008000000000000000
    Library/metadata/00/00000000000000008000000000000000.info
    Library/metadata/00/00000000000000009000000000000000
    Library/metadata/00/00000000000000009000000000000000.info
    Library/metadata/00/0000000000000000a000000000000000
    Library/metadata/00/0000000000000000a000000000000000.info
    Library/metadata/00/0000000000000000a100000000000000
    Library/metadata/00/0000000000000000a100000000000000.info
    Library/metadata/00/0000000000000000b000000000000000
    Library/metadata/00/0000000000000000b000000000000000.info
    Library/metadata/00/0000000000000000c000000000000000
    Library/metadata/00/0000000000000000c000000000000000.info
    Library/metadata/06/0621b4aab2236437592f1f292cb81d20
    Library/metadata/06/0621b4aab2236437592f1f292cb81d20.info
    Library/metadata/0d/0d3bb855445e36e479c85976fc88383a
    Library/metadata/0d/0d3bb855445e36e479c85976fc88383a.info
    Library/metadata/10/10bf81265ad87424d946598c575f45a0
    Library/metadata/10/10bf81265ad87424d946598c575f45a0.info
    Library/metadata/12/12fd8a0055b84bb59e84c9835a37e333
    Library/metadata/12/12fd8a0055b84bb59e84c9835a37e333.info
    Library/metadata/13/1322fd896bbb15bb6e335591b766ae62
    Library/metadata/13/1322fd896bbb15bb6e335591b766ae62.info
    Library/metadata/15/15be9c691b85a41a39c18beeff87e21b
    Library/metadata/15/15be9c691b85a41a39c18beeff87e21b.info
    Library/metadata/15/15bf9c691b85b41a39c18bee2f87e21b
    Library/metadata/15/15bf9c691b85b41a39c18bee2f87e21b.info
    Library/metadata/15/15e327f750b786c46a9ec3995f60c81f
    Library/metadata/15/15e327f750b786c46a9ec3995f60c81f.info
    Library/metadata/19/19e5a138c07e971438b2b18c8e716479
    L
Aborting
```

---

#### Solved

One month's coding of my unity game had vanished for some mistake using git! I force to checkout to my last commit! I've used this

```
git checkout -f 9bd4cdef5fd52edc4fb1c3b8bee83f8b0d888d0c
```

This is the link might help: [The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858047/the-following-untracked-working-tree-files-would-be-overwritten-by-checkout)

Comment: Can you run a git status and copy the output here?

Comment: They did run `git status`, but the post was too poorly formatted to notice it easily.

Comment: Did you save your Unity project and scene before quitting it (both of them)? If you didn't do any `git reset --hard` git won't delete any of your files.

Comment: Are those files in your git repo? Usually the flow is git add, git commit, git push; did you ever push your changes?

Comment: Ok, I've solved it!!! It was devastating for me!! One month's coding of my unity game had vanished for some mistake using git! I force to checkout to my last commit!! I've used this git checkout -f 9bd4cdef5fd52edc4fb1c3b8bee83f8b0d888d0c  this is the like might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858047/the-following-untracked-working-tree-files-would-be-overwritten-by-checkout