# How to get a fresh copy of a branch from the remote repository?

Tags: git

My friend's local `master` branch is apparently a disaster (through accidental `merge`s and `commit`s, I guess). However, his dev branches are fine but contain changes he's not ready to push to remote.

What's the best way of overriding his local `master` branch with the remote `master` branch and get a fresh copy (without overriding his other branches)?

Answer (score 165, accepted):

As Jefromi commented,

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard origin/master
```

does the right thing: setting the master to its origin state. (If you are already on the `master` branch, you can omit the first command.) It also leaves the branch's reflog intact.

---

*Old inferior answer:*

```
git checkout dev
git branch -D master
git checkout master
```

This switches to another branch ("dev" in this case – choose any other branch you might have), deletes the local `master` branch, and then recreates it from `remotes/origin/master` (which might not work depending on your settings and Git version). The last command is often equivalent to

```
git checkout -b master remotes/origin/master
```

Compared to the new answer above this has the disadvantage that the reflog is destroyed and recreated (i.e. you can't as easy undo this if needed), and it is less clear what happens here. Also, you need to have another branch existing to which you can switch during deletion and recreation (but that was the case in the original question).

Comment: Why not just `git reset --hard origin/master`? Also... does that last step even work? Doesn't seem to for me. (`git checkout -b master origin/master` would though.)

Comment: @Jefromi: You are right, I didn't see the obvious solution. The last seems to work for me (checkout has some default if the branch does not exist, but a fitting remote one does). This may depend on the version, though.

Comment: I tried the first solution and it didn't work. Would be nice to edit it out.

Comment: @lulalala With "first" solution you mean the one mentioned as "old" one? For it to work you need to have a local branch named "dev", of course.

Comment: yeah the `checkout dev` one

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with actually deleting the master and re-creating it from origin. Should be totally fresh and gets rid of the untracked files as well. You may prefer to refresh your reflog too.

Comment: will `git reset --hard origin/master` pull changes from `origin/master` and make your `master` branch an exact replica of `origin/master`?

Comment: @SudhirSinghKhanger if you are currently on master, yes. (It won't fetch changes from the remote repository, you'll need to do this first with `git fetch origin` if wanted.)

Answer (score 14):

Paŭlo Ebermann's answer is correct:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard origin/master
```

And add that if you also wish to remove *untracked* files and *ignored* files:

```
git clean -xfn # dry run with -n
```

Source with further details: [How to remove local (untracked) files from the current Git working tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61212/how-do-i-remove-local-untracked-files-from-my-current-git-branch)