# What does Git actually do when I run git checkout branch_name?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I have one repository which is called `test-repo`.

Right now, I have two branches on that repository, called:

1. master
2. master-bkp

Both branches contains only one file called `test.txt`.

`test.txt` in master contains

```
hello I am here
```

and `test.txt` in master-bkp contains

```
hello I am there
```

Now, in my local repository I write:

```
git checkout master
git merge master-bkp
```

Now `test.txt` in master contains

```
hello I am here
hello I am there
```

Can someone explain how Git works internally when I trigger these two commands?

```
git checkout master
git checkout master-bkp
```

**Note :** Please don't give opinions on `git checkout`, I need an explanation about internal logic behind it.

Comment: You probably should give at least some indication of what you _already_ understand about the commands you performed. Otherwise you could be asking someone to explain everything about git from scratch.

Comment: Read this: [Basic branching and merging](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging)

Comment: In the scenario you've described, you only ran `git checkout master` once, just before running the merge. You have not executed `git checkout master-bkp`, not even once. Please clarify your final question, or improve the example so we know why and in what context you are asking about two checkouts.

Comment: Another thing is, why did you include `merge` in your example? You are asking about `checkout`. These two are unrelated. Are you sure you have not mistaken effects of `merge` for effects of `checkout`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure his question is only about `checkout`, maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Git [`checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) is well documented, this is from the doc:

> Updates files in the working tree to match the version in the index or
>   the specified tree. If no paths are given, git checkout will also
>   update HEAD to set the specified branch as the current branch.

Since I know you can read documentation here is how I see it. Git is a revision control system that provides many tools in order to manage your code history. Since you have many branches I will assume you understand correctly how they work. Checkout is only a command you use to move to others branches. The main goal is to updates files in the working tree so you get the data associated with a certain branch.

***Behind the scenes***

There is no magic. Has it said in the doc it only update `HEAD` so you are on the right branch. this is it. Also, as @ quetzalcoatl pointed out, it is important to know that `git checkout` performs a change detection which forbids changing branches while having uncommited work. Performing a `git checkout` can therefore be considered *'safe'*.

**Note**

Sometimes beginners have a hard time understanding the difference between `git checkout` and `git reset`, even though they're completely different. The easiest way to see it in my opinion is :

***What do you want to update ?***

If the answer is my current branch go read the documentation on `git reset`. If your goal is to update your working tree based on another branch then `git checkout` is what you're looking for.

There is only **one exception** to this statement. If your goal is to overwrite **one** file, you can use `git checkout`, take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3949809/7692463).

Comment: `it only update HEAD` and also of course updates files in working copy to match the HEAD -- and in that moment it performs change-detection and nondestructive merges in case you have uncommitted changes in your working copy.. so in fact there's a bit of happening there

Comment: Good point! it is missing the change detection I will add thank you !!

Comment: `git checkout and git reset, even though they're completely different` - consider `git checkout my/directory/foobar.cs` and compare it to the idea of `checkout` and `reset`. This corner case use of checkout IS a one-file reset, and believe me, I've seen a lot of git-for-beginners sites which show that use case of checkout command, claiming it's handy to get a fresh version of a file from current or different branch

Comment: @quetzalcoatl I really appreciate your insight! but I must admit I don't agree with your second comment. That is not how I would recommend approaching such situation. Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657451/how-to-get-a-fresh-copy-of-a-branch-from-the-remote-repository). Updated answer according to your first comment though. Thanks

Comment: @quetzalcoatl oh just noticed you said for one file! I will add a link