# Git remove tracked files from working dir leaving only untracked

Tags: git

Is there a way I can kinda checkout nothing so all tracked files are removed from my working directory?

This way I can just see all my untracked files at glance with normal ls commands.

Also I could `git add .` then  stash the new index if I just wanted to add untracked when I re checkout the branch I came from.

Comment: Not totally sure if i understand you. But i think it might be related to this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61212/how-do-you-remove-untracked-files-from-your-git-working-copy

Comment: Your question title and body are asking opposite things.  Your title is asking to remove un-tracked and your body is asking to remove tracked.

Comment: Wow this confusion has caused a lot of downvotes.

Comment: sabgenton wishes never to typo in his title again :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this would work, but I'd make a backup first..

`git ls-files | xargs rm`

Comment: Why a backup when it is in git?

Comment: I'm not confident enough in my bash skills to say it won't delete something it shouldn't:)

Comment: +1 though...this is what the OP wants, but seriously, he should not be wanting this.

Comment: That looks good for it :D, will consider accepting this answer.

Comment: @manojlds why not every time you checkout a branch it rm's everything tracked and then repopulates with the branch your checking out leaving untracked files untouched (scaryness here)

Comment: @manojlds I would like a nicer way to did it without the bash pipe if thats what you mean.

Comment: @Andy out of interest can I git ls untracked files?

Comment: @sabgenton `git ls-files --exclude-standard --others`  You can leave out `--exclude-standard` if you want to include files from your .gitignore too