# Managing hotfixes when develop branch is very different from master?

Tags: git, git-flow

I'm using the "Git Flow" branching model, with a master branch and a develop branch. I'm working on a major new release, so my develop branch is wildly different from my master branch. This creates a problem anytime I need to make a hotfix on the master branch and merge it back into develop. There are almost always conflicts, and it's becoming a real pain.

What is the best way to manage this? It would be easier for me to make the small hotfix changes on develop manually and then merge everything into master when I'm ready without merging master back into develop. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you considered [cherry-picking](http://technosophos.com/content/git-cherry-picking-move-small-code-patches-across-branches) instead of merging `master` into `develop`?

Comment: By default, with a non FF merge, if you pull develop into master, the tip of develop will not have the master changes, but master will have the develop changes.  Is that what you want?

Comment: @Andy - I basically just want to replace master with develop. I don't want it to complain about master changes not being merged into develop, etc.

Comment: @TaylorOtwell, if that is that case why not just [rename it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21848/switch-branch-names-in-git)

Comment: +1 for being TaylorOtwell

Answer (score 70):

The simplest way to get *some* commits from one branch to another is [cherry-picking](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html).

Assuming that your fix in `master` has the commit hash `HASH` and you want to take that hotfix into your `devel` branch, do a `git checkout devel` followed by a `git cherry-pick HASH`. That's it.

If you want to take *all* changes from `master` into `devel`, you can achieve that with

```
git checkout devel
git rebase master
```

---

If you have the opposite scenario (you make a hotfix during development in a `devel` branch and want to take that fix into `master` before `devel` gets fully merged into `master`), the workflow is quite similar. Assuming that the hotfix has the hash `HOTFIX_HASH`, do this:

```
git checkout master
git cherry-pick HOTFIX_HASH
```

Now, the commit is present in `master` and `devel`. To get around this, type

```
git checkout devel
git rebase master
```

and the commit will disappear from `devel` since it's already present in `master`.

Comment: Please note that `git cherry-pick` creates a different commit. Subsequent merge of `devel` branch into `master` will be conflicted because of that. The solution is only suitable for 'rebase workflow'.

Comment: As implied by @IvanBorisenko, if you're working on devel with anyone else you'll want to `git merge master` instead of rebase to avoid rewriting history. In the second scenario there will then be merge conflicts to resolve.

Comment: Do I need to push to master before I issue the `checkout` and `cherry-pick` commands?

Answer (score 21):

My general workflow for this situation is to create a `bug-fix` branch of `master` that fixes the problem.  Once it's ready, merge that back into `master` then merge `master` into `develop`.

This assumes that your bug fix is almost a one-to-one between the code it needs to change in both branches.  If that's the case, you could always try a `git merge -s ours master` (see [man-page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html#_merge_strategies)) into `develop` so the `develop` branch takes priority.

I use a similar process for managing bug fix releases on an open-source project I'm working on.  `master` is always ahead of where the bug fix needs to be applied, so I create a branch from the tag that needs the fix, apply the fix and release, then retag and merge the new tag into `master`.  This causes a conflict because of the version numbers, but can be avoided with the command above.

Hope that helps.

Comment: why not `git merge -s ours hotfix-2.2` where 2.2 is something I made up

Comment: Between `merge master` and `merge hotfix-*` which one is better the better way?

Answer (score 8):

I usually follow this [guide](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) which fits quite well in most cases and avoids mayor of issues with conflicts and **big** changes.

If you could work on `feature` branches and merge them in `development` only prior to a `release` branch creation (meaning you are actually preparing a release)... this method should avoid most of the merge conflicts you experience.

Since breaking changes would occur at a `feature-breaking` branch, you MAY only have conflicts once at the time this `feature-breaking` branch gets merged into development. And you could as well merge `development` into the `release` branch at any time to keep it updated.

You will also be cool with merging into `development` all the `hotfix-branch`es you have with minimum or non conflicts at all.

The guide I shared on the link before makes big emphasis on never merging from `development` to `master` or backwards. Always handle your releases via a `release` branch.

Comment: This guide is good too: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow

Answer (score 0):

This all depends on how you are going to use GIT to manage your code, your release plan, and your version. The best practise is to have `master` branch to hold your production level code, have `develop` branch to do your development, have `release` branch branched out from `develop` to handle your upcoming releases and `hotfix` branch branched from `master` to handle urgent fixes for production code. So the `release` and `hotfix` branches will finally to be merged back to BOTH `master` and `develop` to make sure both branches have the changes and later on when `develop` branches out new `release` this new release has no problem to merge on `master`. And the tagging will be always on `master`.

With this approach, the `release` and `hotfix` branches will be merged twice and the conflict is sometimes seen when merging to `develop`, which is inevitable if there are many development activities going on `develop`. Shorten your `release` or `hotfix` branch lifecycle could be a way to mitigate this problem. If conflict happens, solve it with whatever techniques and make sure don't change the completed and tested `release` or `hotfix` code.

Answer (score 0):

All answers were smelly.
My personal solution is mid releases.

Once every 3-7 days you do a microrelease

Like you name it 1.01, 1.02 an so on. Next release on customer will be 2.0
Those mid release must include only features that are stable (and thus not merged into master yet)

This allow you to keep master and develop consistent over time and do hotflix with light heart and avoid lot of troubles