# Merging a hotfix branch into master but not dev

Tags: git, version-control

In my project, I have two main branches: `master` and `dev`. I've been doing a lot of work on the `dev` branch as I finish up a new release. I have identified an issue in my current `master` branch that needs to be fixed. The only issue is, in my `dev` branch, I have completely overhauled that same file. When I make a `hotfix` branch, I usually merge it back into both `master` and `dev`. But in a situation like this, I think I would get lots of merge conflicts. Is it okay to simply merge this into `master` without merging it into `dev`? Can I expect merge conflicts when I merge `dev` back into `master`? Thanks!

Comment: Check out this previous issue on branch changes

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175869/managing-hotfixes-when-develop-branch-is-very-different-from-master

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fine not to merge it; but, it is also possible to merge and to resolve all the conflicts in the favor of the `dev` branch.  By doing the merge, you maintain the similarity between the `master` and `dev` branches structure-wise.  The procedure is:

```
$ git checkout dev
$ git merge hotfix
# conflicts arise, use `dev`
$ git checkout --ours -- <filename>  # --ours is the key.
$ git add <filename>
$ git commit ...
```

When you merge `dev` into `master` you might have conflicts but you will revolve them with `--theirs` (use the file from `dev`, not `master`).