# How to move the current working branch to master branch in git

Tags: git

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to move the current working branch to master branch in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161860/how-to-move-the-current-working-branch-to-master-branch-in-git)

I am working in a project with different branches. The latest changes were in some other branch other branch other than master. Now my requirement is, is there any possible ways to move the current working branch to master without merging it with master to avoid conflicts.

If yes please guide me with the necessary commands with comments if possible.

Thanks, Pal