# git commit all, but ignore/exclude a file once

Tags: git

I want to commit a number of files that have changed. Yet, there is one file, which should be excluded only for this commit. Thus, I looking for something like

`git commit -m "Many changes." * -ignore src/later.txt`

Comment: this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7239333/how-do-i-commit-only-some-files

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just do git add . then git reset the file you don't want

```
git add .
git reset src/later.txt
git commit -m "Many changes"
```

Comment: Wouldn't `git add -u` would be better here?

Comment: I don't know if the file the OP is talking about is tracked or not, actually... at least my _hunch_ from reading is that it's a tracked file. But anyway, without knowing if it is tracked or not, we can't really be sure if `-u` would pull it off or not.

Answer (score 0):

to do this you should unstage that particular file using 
"git reset --pathoffile" 
then go ahead commit others