# git add different group of files?

Tags: git

In my situation, I have a webapp (django) project that has a bunch of staged files I'd not like to discard or commit, but at the same time, I have a file (a sqlite file) that I want to add and commit. At this moment since I have no idea how to do this, I'm taking a way to manually copy (cp) the file to an another non-git directory with renaming, but this is apparently not an efficient practice. So what can I do? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the file that you want to commit:

```sh
git commit -m 'commit the file' -- /path/to/file
```

This will commit the specified file but other staged files will not be committed.

Comment: That would be what I wanted, but as I'm trying the command I get `did not match any file(s) known to git.`.

Comment: e.g. `$ git commit -m "sqlite tmp" db.sqlite3` `error: pathspec 'db.sqlite3' did not match any file(s) known to git.`
The file is certainly there and accessible. The file is also not in the gitignore or on the matches.

Comment: Try adding two hyphens before the path (but leave a space between the hyphens and the path).

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but it still doesn't work (`git commit -m "sqlite tmp" -- db.sqlite3`); I get the same above error

Comment: Ah, I misread the error: `did not match any file(s) known to git` means that the file is not tracked by git; you need to do `git add db.sqlite3` before committing.

Comment: made it, thanks. But I googled "git commit specific files" and found a SO post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7239333, no one mention to the trick `--`. I'd like to learn is there any SO post or document that elaborate this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13321458/meaning-of-git-checkout-double-dashes

Answer (score 0):

[stash](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) the staged files, then add and commit the file you want and pop the stash back.