# Telling git its ok to remove untracked files

Tags: git, version-control

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you remove untracked files from your git working copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61212/how-do-you-remove-untracked-files-from-your-git-working-copy)

Is it possible to tell git to remove untracked files? Mainly something that is similar to a reset?

example:

```
git checkout -- index.php <-- revert my file
git checkout -- master <-- this would revert the entire repo back to the last commit on master, removing (deleting) any and all untracked files as well as reverting committed ones.
```

I know this is trivial to do on the shell. But I'd like to know if this can be done in Git?

Comment: `git checkout -- master` will **not** check out branch `master`, but will check out the **file** called `master` at the current commit (`HEAD`)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You may be looking for `git clean`. This will delete all untracked files. By default this ignores (does not delete) patterns in `.gitignore`, but `git clean -x` cleans those files too.

From the `git clean` man page:

```
   -x
       Don't use the ignore rules. This allows removing all untracked
       files, including build products. This can be used (possibly in
       conjunction with git reset) to create a pristine working directory
       to test a clean build.
```

Comment: I have to use `-f` instead. `-x` seems to not work for me, got this error: `fatal: clean.requireForce defaults to true and neither -i, -n nor -f given; refusing to clean`

Comment: @Hlung: It looks like the default for your Git installation is to require `-f`. So you would use `git clean -f -x`.

Answer (score 66):

You need `git clean` but add the `-df` to enable removing files that are in directories from where you are. Add `x` to include ignored files.

So to completely clean your working directory leaving only what is in source control, issue this command:

```
git clean -xdf
```

Comment: upvote indeed. 
http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean

Comment: This is the ultimate answer to the question. Accepted answer clears the inside of an untracked directory but leaves the directory's itself.