# git clean -d -f removes directories containing files which are ignored. Can I keep the ignored files and still run git clean -d

Tags: git, git-clean

`git clean -d -f` removes directories containing files which are ignored.  Can I keep the ignored files and still run `git clean -d`?

Example:

```
dir\dir2\file1
```

*.gitignore*:

```
dir\dir2
```

`git clean -d -f` removes `dir` and all it's contents.  I would expect it to realize that i'm ignoring `dir\dir2\file1` and not delete `file1`.

Comment: You will, soon, with git 1.8.4 and its ***interactive*** `git clean` mode: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17802455/6309

Comment: That is very useful but it's not exactly what i'm looking for.  I would think given that git clean has a -x and -X parameters it can read the .gitignore file, If i don't specify -x or -X i would expect it to leave my ignored files where they are, but it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

I've observed the same behavior and cannot find it listed in a bug. It's certainly still the behavior in `git` 2.0.4.

The work-around i've found it to add a dummy file in the empty directory that is contains the ignored file, so that it is no longer considered by `-d`, e.g.

```
/dir
  /dir2
    /file1
    /.marker
```

Being a *.dotfile* it's ignored from directory listing, so it's fairly unobtrusive and it does keep the directory put.