# What is the low-level command that `git clean` uses to figure out the set of files it wants to clean?

Tags: git

Consider the following command:

```
git clean -n -x -d
```

This produces output of the following form:

```
Would remove path/to/file/1
Would remove untracked/directory
```

I would like to run a different command X on these files, but the extra `Would remove` prefix is not useful.

I could run `sed` or `cut` to kill this prefix.

```
 git clean -n -x -d  | cut -c 14-
```

However, I'm curious about whether there's a lower level `git` plumbing command I can use the get the output I want without starting another process.

`git ls-files --other`  seemed promising, but unfortunately, its output includes all the files, instead of just the directory containing all the files.

```
path/to/file/1
untracked/directory/file1
untracked/directory/file2
...
```

**Is there a low-level git command to replicate the output of `git clean` above without the extra prefix, or is my cleanest option just to `cut` out the prefix?**

Comment: I would use `awk`. `git clean -n -x -d | awk '{print $3}'`?

Comment: Doing `| cut -c 14-` seems not smart, seeing the output (from `git clean`) in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8638562/git-clean-what-does-would-not-remove-mean

Comment: @evolutionxbox: And hope your filenames do NOT contain spaces.

Comment: @evolutionxbox only works with some locales ;) "Would remove" could be more or less than 2 words in other languages.

Comment: @Luuk hahaha. _live on the edge_

Comment: If you really want to use awk, use `gawk` and do: `echo Would remove a b c d | gawk '/^Would remove/{ $1=null; $2=$1; FS="\x00"; $0=$0; gsub(/^ */,"",$1); }1'`, to get the filename with spaces as output.

Comment: @Luuk The warning is much appreciated!

Comment: Side note: `git clean` does this internally, not by running a separate plumbing command. Fortunately `git ls-files`, as a separate plumbing command, has the capabilities you want. Note that `git clean` does however play tricks with ignored files (`-x` vs `-X`), so to cover everything gets complicated.

Comment: @torek Are you implying that the second command in the answer will not always produce the same output as my command above?

Comment: @merlin2011: `git clean -fX` (you're not using uppercase X, but I'm trying to cover all cases here) removes *only* **ignored** files, so it does not remove files printed as `??` by `git status --short`, for instance. Meanwhile `git status -x` skips the `.gitignore` files, so that no files are ignored (unless you add `-e` arguments, which are another way `git clean` can do weird special cases).

Comment: Besides this, `git status` says nothing about empty directories (those with no files in them), but `git clean -d` will remove them. I'm pretty sure `git ls-files --others` never mentions empty directories either. Let me test it... yes, `git clean -ndx` prints `Would remove empty/` but neither `git ls-files` nor `git status` mention it (under any circumstances).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to get near git's plumbing, you can list untracked files with:

```
git ls-files --others
```

Alternatively, you can stick with commonly known tools, i.e.

```
git status --short --ignored | grep '!!\|??'
```

Documentation:

- [`git-ls-files`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files)
- [`git-status`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status)

Comment: The second command was precisely the one I was looking for.