# How to remove new files from a directory?

Tags: git

I'm used to do this when I want to rollback changes in a directory:

```
$ git checkout path/to/dir/
```

But now I need to remove files that have been created (not modified) in that dir, and checkout didn't work. What can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`git clean -f` or `git clean -f -d` if you also want to remove directory. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61212/removing-untracked-files-from-your-git-working-copy)
Also check out the [official documentation](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clean.html)