How to differentiate between a branch and tag with same name in git?
I learned the hard way that you should not name a tag the same as a branch, anyway...
How do I perform e.g. git merge <name> and specify that it is a branch and not a tag or vice versa?

You need to use the reference's unambiguous name, for example refs/heads/<name> or refs/tags/<name>

@RichardSmith I just figured that out too a minute ago, thanks though!

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/68040205/341994 (or the Git docs) for how Git resolves names if you don't use the "unambiguous" name. You've been taking advantage of this resolution process all this time without knowing it!

I knew I once encountered some other issue and the solution was to use refs/something/something/branch_name and I know that all these are just files underneath the .git\ folder.
This is what I did:

Open or tree the hidden .git\ folder in your repo (on windows)

# opens Windows Explorer
repos\project1> start .git
# or
repos\project1> tree /F .git\refs


Browse the \.git\refs folder and in there observe

├───refs
│   ├───heads
│   │   │   guides
│   │   │   main
│   │   ...
│   │
│   └───tags
│           docs
│           guides
...




What can be seen there is the basis for uniquely identifying a resource.
Now what's left is to just do:
git merge refs/heads/guides

or
git merge refs/tags/guides

