# Yeoman source folders (what to import in version control)

Tags: yeoman

I'm new to Yeoman/Grunt/Bower and I'd like someone knowledgeable to tell me what the best practice for importing the generated scaffold to version control is.

For example, I've created an angular project with "yo angular" using version 1.0.7-pre.2 of Yeoman and clearly there's some stuff that gets downloaded by bower/npm, which is "safe" to keep out of source control, like:

1. folder "node_modules" (can be re-created with "npm update")
2. folder "app/bower_components" (can be re-created with "bower update)

Is there anything else that should be kept out of source control?

Is there some clean task that will automatically remove all such files? (I've discovered "grunt clean" but that seems to leave both bower_components and npm_modules intact).

Is there some scaffold that will generate a "best practice" .gitignore?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As for deleting untracked files: http://stackoverflow.com/a/64966/1432478

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Had I bothered to actually check I would have found that Yeoman actually *does* generate a .gitignore file:

```
$ cat .gitgnore
node_modules
dist
.tmp
.sass-cache
app/bower_components
```