# How to remove untracked files except the ones in .gitignore?

Tags: git

Say I crete some files for experimenting without committing them. `git status` shows:

```
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

  file a
  file b

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

If I run `git clean -f` it will remove files a and b, but also other untracked files, such as `node_modules`, tmp files etc., which are included under `.gitignore`. Is there a git command to remove only the untracked files shown under `git status` or must I remove them manually with `rm`?

Comment: See similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61212/removing-untracked-files-from-your-git-working-copy

Comment: @jayalalk maybe I am missing something, but I don't see the option there to NOT remove ignored files.

Comment: Git ignores stuff in .gitignore... I'll let that sink in for a moment.

Comment: Not removing ignored files is the default. The `-x` option also removes ignored files. See `git help clean`.

Comment: @anddoutoi Not true. In my `.gitignore` file I have `node_modules/*`. After running `git clean -fd` node_modules is gone.

Comment: It's cause your pattern is wrong. `node_modules/*` ignores everything that is child of `node_modules/`. Use only `node_modules` and will probably do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments and [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61212/removing-untracked-files-from-your-git-working-copy) - by default `git clean` does not remove ignored files. To include them, one must use the either `-x` (ignored and non-ignored files) or `-X` (ignored file only). However, if under `.gitignore` one specifies a pattern like `folder_name/*` and then use the `-d` option, it will also remove `folder_name`.