# Git Stash equivalent of --theirs

Tags: git

I'm fairly new to git via command line, but I've seen that you can use --theirs and --ours to resolve merge conflicts - But this seems to only work with git checkout. Is there a way to do a similar thing when using git stash pop / git stash apply? i.e. When I pop from the stash it creates a load of conflicts. Rather than resolve each one individually, is there a way to instantly resolve them all one way or the other?

Thanks

Answer (score 22):

In addition to @[r3mus-n0x](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9435815/r3mus-n0x) answer, you should provide the index of stash you want to check out. Then the fatal error should not occur.

```
$> git stash list
   stash@{0}: WIP on xxx: 466a845fe Fix: Deleted unnecessary comments

$> git checkout stash@{0} --theirs .
```

Confirmed with git-version 2.28.0

Comment: Worked exactly as I was hoping it would. Back of my mind I wonder if a new/untracked file wasn't added... but it was nbd.

Comment: @DevinRhode untracked files are stored differently in stash. They are stored in and you can access them in the third parent. Or you use the commit SHA:

# 3rd parent Method
$> git checkout stash@{0}^3 -- path/to/file

# SHA Method
# 1st find the SHA of untracked:
$> git log --name-status stash@{0}  
# then check it out
#> git checkout SHA -- path/to/file

Comment: @DevinRhode here I found a good described post https://stackoverflow.com/a/23609023/2408013

Comment: In git 2.43.0, the command `git checkout 'stash@{0}' --theirs -- xxx.file` gets error `fatal: '--merge', '--ours', or '--theirs' cannot be used when checking out of a tree` but it works well in 2.42.

Answer (score 5):

You can still use `git checkout` with the current directory as an argument:

```
git checkout --theirs .
```

Comment: That's useful to know, unfortunately this gives an error of:
`fatal: '--ours/--theirs' cannot be used with switching branches`

Comment: @Kieran, please provide the exact steps that led you to this error.