# git clean does nothing

Tags: git, git-clean

I am trying to clean my working tree, however, when I enter `git clean --force` nothing happens.

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.2.0.30506.0/
        packages/Microsoft.Data.Edm.5.2.0/
        packages/Microsoft.Data.OData.5.2.0/
        packages/Microsoft.Net.Http.2.0.20710.0/
        packages/Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.1.0.0.0/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

$ git clean  --force

$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.2.0.30506.0/
        packages/Microsoft.Data.Edm.5.2.0/
        packages/Microsoft.Data.OData.5.2.0/
        packages/Microsoft.Net.Http.2.0.20710.0/
        packages/Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.1.0.0.0/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Likewise, `git clean -i` has no effects either.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove local (untracked) files from my current Git branch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61212/remove-local-untracked-files-from-my-current-git-branch)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These are all **directories**, in order to remove **directories** you need to use the command :

```
git clean -f -d
```

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64966/442351).