# Remove unused assets from git history

Tags: git, git-filter-branch, git-rewrite-history

So, I've been searching all morning for the correct way to do this, and I'm just not that command line savvy to figure it out.

I have a git repo with a ton of assets in it. It's like the cardinal sin, I know.

The repo has grown to be too huge. I'd like to clean it up so I can programmatically remove all files that do not exist in HEAD anymore from the entire history of the repo. I've seen ways to do this where you can specify the file paths, but really, I am talking like 1000+ files that have been removed from our final product that I really don't care to have in my repo anymore.

**UPDATE:**
I've cleaned the repo of all the assets that shouldn't have been there in the first place. I really just have source code in there now and a few assets that SHOULD be there. I'd really love to keep all the history of all the source code... so I'm really looking to scrap the deleted files from history while preserving the history what currently exists. That's the goal. I am pretty sure it can be done using `git filter-branch` - but I just don't understand it well enough.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61212/remove-local-untracked-files-from-my-current-git-branch

Comment: See update. I don't think so.

Comment: at this point you have a garden variety filter branch problem.  Something like `git filter-branch --index-filter "git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch $files" HEAD` plus the other cleanup steps from filter branch documentation should work for you.

Comment: [Were none of these satisfactory](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=remove+objects+from+repository)?

Comment: The problem is that I don't fully understand how to populate the $files variable with what I need. Not fluent enough in command line syntax. A lot of what I found on the internet allowed you to remove specific files, but nothing great that told you how to remove old files and protect files on HEAD.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [BFG Repo-Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/), a simpler, faster alternative to `git-filter-branch` specifically designed for removing unwanted files from Git history.

> so I can programmatically remove all files that do not exist in HEAD anymore from the entire history of the repo

By default, the BFG 'protects' all files in your HEAD commit, but will delete other files that match your criteria.

You should carefully follow the [usage instructions](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/#usage), but the core part is just this:

```
$ java -jar bfg.jar  --strip-blobs-bigger-than 1M  my-repo.git
```

Any files over 1MB in size - that *aren't* in your latest commit - will be removed from your Git repository's history. If you have normal, smaller-than-1MB, source files that you **still** want to remove, you can specify them with the `--delete-files` or `--delete-folders` options.

The BFG is typically at least [10-50x](http://youtu.be/Ir4IHzPhJuI) faster than running `git-filter-branch`, and generally easier to use.

*Full disclosure: I'm the author of the BFG Repo-Cleaner.*

Comment: Honestly, I've been trying to use your program all day, as it sounded perfect. I didn't realize it protected HEAD files by default. This worked perfectly. Not even sure what my issue was earlier today where I couldn't get this working. Thanks so much! Additionally, it appears you need to run:
$ git reflog expire --expire=now --all
$ git gc --prune=now --aggressive

Answer (score 1):

You could make a shallow clone of the repository and make that the new "main" repository, with the old crufty one saved somewhere else.

`git clone --depth=1 oldrepo newrepo`

This way any files that were deleted are no longer reachable in the new clone, so they won't be stored as Git objects.

The downside of course is that this hides file change history, but it's still accessible in your original repo.

Answer (score 0):

backup your data first, this barely tested!

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'for i in $(git diff master --summary --diff-filter=A | grep "create mode" | cut -d " " -f 5-); do 
    rm "$i"
done' --prune-empty HEAD
```