# How to git delete client branch not in server branch

Tags: git, command

How to git delete client branch not in server branch

without use git delete branch by branch

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove local (untracked) files from my current Git branch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61212/remove-local-untracked-files-from-my-current-git-branch)

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about remote tracking branches (which could track non-existent branches on the remote side), then that would be [`git remote prune`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote):

```
git remote prune origin --dry-run
```

See:

```
prune
```

> Deletes all stale remote-tracking branches under `<name>`.
>   These stale branches have already been removed from the remote repository referenced by `<name>`, but are still locally available in "`remotes/<name>`".
>
> With `--dry-run` option, report what branches will be pruned, but do not actually prune them.

More details in "[Delete a Git branch both locally and remotely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23961231/6309)", which also points out:

```
git fetch origin --prune
git fetch origin -p # Shorter
```