# remove untracked files from app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

In my app I want to revert all the changes which I have done. I have modified few files, deleted a couple of files and added a few files at the same time.

All these changes are untracked. How can I revert everything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

will revert all the changes to tracked files.  To remove untracked files, see this post for various situations/options:

[How to remove local (untracked) files from the current Git working tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61212/how-do-i-remove-local-untracked-files-from-my-current-git-branch)

Comment: will the deleted files come back?

Comment: @Suraj if they were previously committed into your Git repo, then yes.