# how to update local unrevisioned files with git repository

Tags: git, git-pull, git-clone

I have a git repository with 2-3 GB size of files and the same files I have on my local machine as backup. How do I clone the git repository on my local so that it replaced my unversioned files with git repo files to save time and bandwidth.

Comment: Are they exactly the same files?

Comment: this will be help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61212/how-do-i-remove-local-untracked-files-from-my-current-git-branch?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this, but in theory, I think it should work:

First, init a new git repository in the folder where you have the local files with `git init` and add the correct remote with `git remote add ...`

Then, create the blobs from your local files with `git hash-object`:

```
git hash-object -w file1
git hash-object -w file2
git hash-object -w file3
```

At this point, move the local files away from the git managed directory so that they do not interfere.

After that, do `git pull` - it should not download the blobs that you already have. Note that if these files have changed at some point in the repositorys history, it will download the older versions.