# How to checkout to my last commit and delete the current working directory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

Here's the full situation:

1. The commit below is my last commit ever made.

   ```
   commit 2d1efd9c58b44542f81ccba6e33eb698665e7fec
   Author: Jeramae Bohol <mr.jeramaebohol@gmail.com>
   Date:   Thu May 12 07:00:14 2016 +0000

   Add account activations
   ```
2. Then after that commit, I made a big mistake deleting the wrong migration file but the good thing is I haven't commit this yet.

My question is, how can I checkout to my last commit and ignore/delete this one that I made a mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`git reset`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) to your last commit & make sure it will delete all your uncommitted files/codes:

```
git reset --hard 2d1efd9c58b44542f81ccba6e33eb698665e7fec
```

Comment: This is the message after I ran your code: HEAD is now at 2d1efd9 Add account activations. Then when I ran git status, the files that I want to be deleted are still present but just untracked. How can I completely discard all the things I made after my last commit?

Comment: @JeramaeBohol 'git commit' would discard untracked files.

Comment: but there's nothing to commit because the files I want to be deleted are all untracked.

Comment: @JeramaeBohol http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61212/how-do-i-remove-local-untracked-files-from-my-current-git-branch

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this

since you have deleted file after the commit

```
git status
```

now copy your deleted filepath

run this command

```
git checkout deleted_filepath
```

Answer (score 0):

Add that file path to your .gitignore file and then commit your .gitignore file

```
 /log/*
!/log/.keep
/tmp
/path_to_your_migration_file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write command

```
git checkout file_path
```

It will add your deleted file to your directory